# Close vote superpowers for other badges in low volume tags

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, tag-badges

Now that people can [wield Mjölnir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212) I want a go of that mighty hammer!

Having gold badge users with superpowers in their tag is a great idea for high traffic tags. It will not help low traffic tags. For example, I joined Stack Overflow almost six years ago (shortly after the beta). Given there were Jon Skeets in the popular tags I carved out a little niche for myself in the [reporting-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reporting-services) tag.

Usually in that tag there's me, some drive-by 1-rep users and tumbleweeds. I am the [third highest rep user](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reporting-services/topusers) in that tag, most of my rep comes from that tag and I still only have a bronze badge for the tag.

If I get a response for my answers it is often only "Thanks, that worked!" with no accept or up-votes, occasionally accepts with no up-vote if I'm lucky - so much so that for a long time my only gold badge was [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) (until I did enough reviews to at least get another one). [My highest voted answer for this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048363/ssrs-2005-set-simplepageheaders-on-the-report-instead-of-the-server/3058576#3058576), which was answered four years ago, has only 13 votes.

The two users higher than me in the [reporting-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reporting-services) tag have silver tag badges. There are no gold badge users in this tag.

So the [reporting-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reporting-services) tag can't be helped by close-as-duplicate superpowers because there are no gold badge users and probably won't be for around five years at the current rate. There is just not enough voting going on in that tag.

The most popular repeating question, which is answered multiple times, is [ssrs iif or switch gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150462/ssrs-iif-or-switch-gives-error) which was asked again today. Notwithstanding that the questioner could find the answer with a simple internet search faster than they could type the question into Stack Overflow and would have seen the duplicates on Stack Overflow when typing the question, the question still gets asked.

I voted to close it as a duplicate four hours ago but given the low traffic in this tag no one else has yet voted to close it as a duplicate. It may never get closed as a duplicate.

What is more likely is that while we're waiting for five people to vote to close, someone will go "Hey, I know the answer - free points!" and answer it and Stack Overflow's quality gets diluted just a bit further.

*So perhaps for low traffic tags with no or few gold badge users, we could extend the close-as-duplicate superpower to silver badge users, and if there are no or few of them to bronze badge users as well.*

Help us users out on the fringes to clean up our little corners of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is a fundamental problem with the whole SO design. Users who only lurk around less popular tags can be ever so active, helpful and competent, they will still get less badges and less rep than average Joe who only visits one of the mainstream tags. Also, the insta-close-as-duplicate superpower is more useful in less popular tags, because those are less likely to gather the 5 close votes needed.

Comment: Badges seem like an awfully arbitrary demarcation. Why can't this privilege be awarded by top % of users in a tag instead, so long as the tag is "established" (the merits of which could probably fill another discussion)?

Comment: Maybe we should scale it? So the the top users and those with gold have superpowers?

Comment: @HyperAnthony If you get a gold badge you probably *are* a "top X% of user" in the tag. Even in the most popular tags when you reach the gold tag you are pretty surely in the top 10% for the tag. To significantly change the people who'd get the superpowers you'd have to choose an extremely low % (like 1%, 0.5%), and at that point there would be so few people with superpowers that they wouldn't make such a big difference, which would render the whole thing insignificant.

Comment: Would it help if bronze badges counted as 2 votes, silver as 3, gold as 5?

Comment: @Bakuriu This question is addressing tags that take a long time to accumulate *any* users with gold badges.  In some cases, years.  Delimiting privilege by an arbitrary number of points is stifling the efforts of dedicated users in these tags.

Comment: All gold badge holders plus any in top x% who do not have one.

Comment: there should be also a correlation with number of posts under that tag. some kind of signal/noise ration as well. but I think it is a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to the meta effect, your votes are now rising :)

Comment: No, this is a bad idea.  There's already quite a problem with high-reputation or conventionally empowered users making a mess while trying to curate topics they don't understand, the last thing we need is more people given superpowers in areas where they lack expertise or investment of interest.

Comment: Maybe extend the close-as-duplicate power to the highest available badges. This would be gold badges in popular tags and silver badges in reporting services and maybe even bronze badges in some niche tags.

Comment: @TimB That was an unexpected side effect, plus the post is now closed as duplicate. I should post on meta more often! :)

Comment: @HyperAnthony I was originally thinking the top 5 or 10 users but as you say that has issues for new tags. Using badges ensures the user has a certain level of involvement in the tag already and that the tag is fairly established.

Comment: I also suffer this problem [in my own niche](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cakephp/topusers) - me, "mark" and "ADmad" are part of the core team responsible for CakePHP development - and it looks like it'll take me another 2-5 years to achieve a gold badge  (at least mark is almost there), despite a concerted effort to contribute for a 2 years+ since SO was adopted as an official support medium.

Comment: @RobEarl Good, i like your approach.

Comment: @AD7six With more software teams using Stack Overflow as their prime support platform, it makes sense that the core team should have access to the Mjölnir powers without having to jump through a lot of hoops.

Comment: I'd be dead keen on something that could support even lower traffic badges, i.e. [jQuery TokenInput](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-tokeninput/topusers) and its 200 questions.

Comment: What if having the silver tag badges made each close votes count as 2.5 normal close votes?

Comment: @RobEarl You should add that as an answer

Comment: @Bakuriu "If you get a gold badge you probably are a "top X% of user" in the tag. "  Yes, but the problem is that you can be in the top X% without getting a gold badge.  I'm the top user in [tag:rdf], [tag:sparql], [tag:owl], and second or third in some others.  I only just got a few silver tag badges fairly recently.  :\  I recognize a bunch of duplicates (because I answered the originals!), but it's still hard to get these closed because it takes so long to accumulate close votes on some of these.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'm in the same situation as you are, but in the [dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo)  tag. Just like you I'm in the top 5 of the tag answerers, but due to the low amount of questions I only have a bronze badge (and nobody even has a silver badge).

There are a lot of questions that usually have 1 or 2 close votes, but never actually are getting closed (at least not until I lose track of them).

I think that any automatic system will probably fail to detect the proper people for wielding the mighty hammer. And I don't even think all people who reached the "hammer-thresholds" want these extra permissions (or are active today).

So, like [@Veedrac](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260219/1915448) said, the "ask and you shall receive" system would have my vote. Though, I don't think that they should grant gold tag badges, but maybe a seperate thing just to handle these permissions. But to prevent mass-requests, a user should have the following (no idea if these are good thresholds though):

- The user must be part of the top 20 users of the latest month (to make sure the user is still an active community member)
- The tag must have at least N amount of questions (to prevent people in unspecific tags to be able to apply
- The user must have at least a silver tag bage or a bronze tag badge (maybe give the bronze badge holders a less powerful hammer that requires 2 votes)
- The user must have a reviewer badge (to make sure the user is familiar with the closing system)
- The user must have at least a certain amount of questions answered in that tag (to prevent people that have a lot of votes in just 1 or 2 questions to be able to wield the hammer)
- The user must have the Yearling badge (to make sure the user is familiar with SO)
- The user must have N amount of helpful flags (to make sure the user is familiar with the system)

If it's an opt-in system, maybe you could also think about an opt-out system as well, because I don't know if all gold badge holders want the powers they have been granted.

---

I personally would be happy if it only required 2 votes of active users in a tag to close a question, because that's all we actually need.

Comment: Agreed, I'm not after a gold tag badge, I just want to be able to close duplicates. @luk32 had a suggestion in @Veedrac's answer about a `*tag*-sheriff` badge that is along these lines and I think this suggestion is a good solution (so you would get a `dojo-sheriff` badge, I would get a `reporting-services-sheriff` badge). Your criteria are very sensible to prevent abuse, particularly the review badge, tag badge and yearling badge requirements. I like this a lot.

Comment: Also, I don't think gold tag badge holders know that they have had this power thrust upon them. Moderation powers should be opt-in so maybe the feature could be that a user can request to be a `*tag*-sheriff` on the tag page; if the user has a gold tag badge or if the user fulfils your listed requirements then the `*tag*-sheriff` badge is automatically awarded. This way it doesn't even need moderator intervention to award the power and only those who want it, get it.

Comment: @ChrisLätta The gold badge system is working fine; there's no need to complicate it by forcing gold badge owners to request it.

Comment: @DimitriM Do you really need so many rules? It seems like bureaucracy for the sake of bureaucracy, especially with the stuff about flagging. I think the parts about needing a silver/bronze badge are especially redundant. I like points **1, 4, 5 and 6** and I think you should replace point 2 with just "it must be a specific tag". But overall I do like this.

Comment: @Veedrac Oh, these are just ideas that came up to my mind. Maybe they're not all necessary, but I think there should be enough rules to prevent that too many people can opt in (and to make the lifes easier of the people who are going to grant us these permissions).

Comment: @Veedrac Some people with gold tag badges seem shocked by their sudden power but you're right, it probably makes more sense to give them the power and let them deal with it than wait for people to opt in to a system they don't know exists.

Comment: I think the gold badge holders should indeed keep their powers, but I was thinking of giving them the possibility to get rid of it (but that's probably beyond this topic).

Comment: The thing I like about the rules is that it can be a system that doesn't require an investment of moderator time, Mjölnir can be awarded automatically on request if you meet some conditions like: *your tag has at least 2,000 questions and less than 20 gold tag badge holders, and you have a yearling badge, any tag badge, and a gold review badge, and you are one of the top 20 active users in the last month and top 20 overall*. If there are already 20 gold tag badge holders, then they are already doing this job and we don't need to pre-emptively hand out Mjölnir.

Comment: I like the volunteer-and-ye-shall-receive approach a lot. Volunteers are often the life blood of sites like this. The arbitrary means by which moderation privileges are established is not conducive to short term solutions (long term, I think it's a bit more effective)

Comment: Can't nearly all questions tagged dojo also legitimately be tagged [tag:javascript]?  @lukasz rightly points out that we should beware super powers on a minor tag to trump the major one.  I'm also wary of how very complicated the conditions outlined here are.

Comment: @BradKoch that would be a possibility, but a JavaScript "expert" (= a gold tag badge holder?) is not necessarily a Dojo "expert". For example, a while back I encountered a question that was being closed as a duplicate of a JavaScript question, but it had, in fact, nothing to do with it. The only thing they had in common was that it looks similar. Besides that, I don't think people active in the JavaScript tag know which questions are duplicates and which aren't.

Answer (score 13):

This makes sense. There are some minor considerations to be had, though.

#### Just rewarding the top fraction of participants to a tag? No.

If gold badges were *replaced* with a percentage, there would be a big problem. For high-volume tags where moderation is sorely needed, duplicates are harder to find and questioner's standards tend to be lower, it doesn't make much sense to deny the help of a long-time answerer just because someone else has 20 thousand rep. You also don't want to be retracting privileges because *other* people are active. That's just unfair.

#### Just gold badges? Well, that's what the post is about...

Chris Lätta's answers are good. He's obviously not asking for privileges prematurely. There's no doubt he represents the best of his tag, and it makes sense to improve his ability to moderate.

#### But how?

- **Top N**, or **top N%**?

  The big warning here is that the tag needs to be important and stand-alone for this to be a good idea. We don't want to be giving people moderation powers because they are top 10% in a tag with 12 questions. This is *especially* true as tags can be constructed artificially, and there are many ways of (mis)using them to do more than just close as duplicate.

  We don't want to give out trust for free.
- **Top N**, or **top N%** on tags with a certain activity and age minimum?

  This sounds reasonable and I certainly don't think it's a terrible idea. I don't know what limits are sufficiently non-arbitrary, though.
- **Ask and you shall receive**?

  Why don't we just allow moderators to hand out gold tag badges to members who demonstrate exceedingly good contribution, on request. We could require a post on Meta with a quick round on voting, with the simple rules of

  - It has to have few gold badge users
  - It must be an active and maintained tag
  - It must be a *specific* tag, so no hand-outs for [nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested)
  - The user must deserve it

  This seems like a reasonably low-volume task and has far fewer repercussions than the current blind handouts that currently happen. There is little chance of misuse, especially if you've *just put yourself under Meta's scrutiny*.

  i can haz?

Comment: "Ask and you shall receive" actually sounds like the least problematic route to me.

Comment: I somehow don't like the idea of giving away the gold badge on request. The criteria are too vague and arbitrary, I especially dislike the idea of  assigning badges only as a mean to give power to some individuals. This in not what a badge is for. More-over it would be reversing of what it is now. You get powers, because you have badge. Not get badge to have powers. Unless they would introduce `*tag*-sheriff` badges to distinct it. Now it's a trophy for getting rep with respect to tag. Idea that someone can get it by being chosen seems a little bit unfair.

Comment: I do, however, agree that 5-10% of most reputable users could have super powers on tags meeting certain criteria, like total questions/answers and followers. Though, I believe one should have rights to use super powers only basing on the questions' most-popular tag, this would limit "leaks/floods of powers". Although I am not sure if the last one is a good idea, because the tags can be easily edited, now it is essentially the same, one could add a tag the they have powers in, and use them.

Comment: @luk32 gold badge superpowers only work if you have gold badge in a tag that was included originally on the post. You can't just edit in your own tags to gain superpowers.

Comment: I like the second point of "Top N, or top N% on tags with a certain activity and age minimum" Could you elaborate it more ?

Comment: My original idea was if the top 5 users could at least put a question on hold until we can generate the 5 votes to close it but we don't really have 5 people with vote-to-close privileges in this tag. Also if it were the top 5 users you could invent a tag, apply it to one of your top answers, apply it to another user's question then wield the vote-to-close hammer, so that seems open to abuse. You should have at least some badge in the tag to demonstrate your history with no or few people with higher badges. This helps low traffic tags while protecting high traffic tags.

Comment: *"the top 5 users you could invent a tag, apply it to one of your top answers, apply it to another user's question then wield the vote-to-close hammer"* That does not work. Only the tags of the first revision of a question are considered for the close-superpower.

Comment: @luk32 I like the `*tag*-sheriff` badge idea. You should expand on that in a separate answer.

Comment: Actually, I don't think handing out the gold-badge is such a good idea, and that is not what the OP is asking for. I don't think it is a good idea because that would betray its description, and the OP is not asking for a gold-badge, just pointing out that awarding the mighty hammer only to gold-badge holders has its limits.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The description can be changed. Or you could have an "honorary" variant of the badge which is similar but has a different description and variant name.

Comment: @Veedrac: I am fine with having an honorary, but I would still prefer to decorrelate it from super-powers.

Comment: You're basically suggesting sub-moderators for sub-communities. This is why having so many communities under one roof is broken.

Comment: For the ask-and-you-shall-receive, condition that "It has to have few gold badge users" seems too limiting.  E.g., take a look at [sparql's top users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sparql/topusers).  We're active, and there are plenty of questions coming though, but still no gold badge users… [common-lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/common-lisp/topusers) is another.  Some traffic and active users, but only one gold badge.  I think that any solution explicitly needs to avoid criteria like "It has to have few gold badge users" because not having that is the **problem** in the first place.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Are you thinking that "it has to have few" means "it has to have a few"? Because I think we agree. "it has to have few" means "it can't have many". Zero, by that count, is few.

Comment: @Veedrac Ooops, I completely read it as "It has to have [a] few gold badge users."  Sorry, I shouldn't post before morning coffee.  Yes, we absolutely agree.  Thank you for your patience. :)

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, the idea of only trusting gold-badge members was a quick & dirty approach which has good results (though now I am wary of voting to close as duplicate knowing there is no second opinion) but is also limited.

It seems to me that there are two solutions:

- granting "super-powers" to lesser tags (silver: 4, bronze: 3, or whatever) is one such way
- the other would be to hand out a specific Mjölnir badge (tag-specific): automatically if you reach the gold badge in this tag, and otherwise on request (Meta)

I would actually prefer the second solution, as it decorrelates two notions (awards and power) that are not equivalent.

Comment: TBH I'm fine with separating the badge and the power; I just don't see why people feel any need to do so. I *very much* dislike giving too much emphasis on bronze badges, though. It would have been way too early for me. Further, it would make it far too easy to close as duplicate on high volume tags.

Comment: @Veedrac: I agree that having the complete hammer for bronze badges is too early, however requesting only 3 bronze-badge holders or 2 silver-badge holders for closing duplicates seems alright. TBH, I am not that comfortable in being able to close questions with a single vote; I am human, I make mistakes :x

Comment: I did understand that from what you said before. I still think bronze is too early for a lot of tags. You can get it before you've even permission to vote to close!

Comment: Heck, I got my silver badge **the day after I got close vote powers**. I *really* don't think saying I'm immediately deserving of triple-close points is a good idea.

Comment: It's different for certain niche tags, I mean, in the tag I'm often answering questions at, nobody got a silver badge as of now and the people close to it left for more than a year now.

Comment: Niche tags are special - I have well over the number of answers required for a gold tag badge but not enough points for a silver tag badge. Tags with a lot of drive-by 1-rep users don't get many votes because low rep users don't yet have the vote-up privilege. Maybe you need to fulfil the gold tag badge answers target (200) even though you don't fulfil the points requirement before you can get the Mjölnir tag badge. That way you at least partially meet the "gold standard".

Comment: @ChrisLätta: Unfortunately automatically awarding the badge for just a number of answers target would mean rewarding (potentially) spammers. That's why I like Veedrac's suggestion of just asking for it on Meta, there human beings can evaluate whether it's warranted or not.

Comment: No, I wasn't suggesting just for a level of answers but that the "gold standard" answer level might be a minimum requirement along with the other requirements in @DimitriM's answer. Along the lines of *you would normally have a gold badge with your participation level but for some reason people don't vote in your tag so you haven't made the score requirement; however, you have met these other criteria indicating you are a good citizen, so we are going to trust you with Mjölnir within your tag*

Answer (score -11):

**TL/DR** Golden Hammer is enough, don't add Silver and Bronze ones!

If you visit [Jon Skeet profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), you'll see that he doesn't get much reputation from his answers because they are in very popular tag. In fact, he gets very little reputation from statistical answer: a bit more than 20. The same was for another few randomly checked top users.

I don't see the situation being other in low popularity tags. Even if you get a single upvote and your answer is accepted, you have better average than Jon Skeet, wow!

The concept of **The Golden Hammer**, as I understand it, is not to be a top-N user in the given tag, it's about having **really very many** good answers in that tag! For **thousands** of good answers!

No matter if the tag has heavy traffic or not, you'd probably have to give the similar amount of answers to get the Golden Hammer. Reducing the requirements in low-traffic tags would be allowing to get it too easily. Having 'only' **hundreds** of answers is (and should be) not enough.

What's worse: having Golden Hammer in a niche tag will allow you **to close questions in heavy-traffic tag**, if the question happen to be tagged with both! It would **circumvent** the requirements!

Yeah, the problem is with low-popularity languages where you simply don't have enough questions. But if the topic is not explored enough, maybe giving such powers is not a good idea anyway?

A [dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo) example is something a bit else. Dojo isn't a language but only a library. The questions about given library may or may not be tagged with the language tag, but tagging it with the language tag is generally appropriate, and allows golden hammer strike, in that case, for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) golden badgers. A plenty of library tags has golden badgers as well. So it's enough!

Comment: So your argument is that because someone has a gold tag badge in `javascript` it is reasonable to expect them to be expert enough in `dojo` to be able to close duplicates with both the `dojo` and `javascript` tags? Or that having a close powers in a niche tag should prevent you closing questions that are also tagged with a more popular tag when it is probably that niche expertise that is required to recognise a duplicate?

Comment: If Dojo is a JS library, then questions on it _should_ be tagged [tag:javascript] already. I'm sure that many aren't, though, and the mighty hammer only considers original tags.

Comment: I don't see it as 'circumventing the requirements' - the requirements is having tgh in one of the tags. Assuming it is tagged correctly (a different issue), then (to consider) the `dojo`/`javascript` example. It means someone in the top % of people for `dojo` can close `dojo` tagged questions. Yes they happen to also be `javascript` questions, but so what? Equally, someone with tgh in `javascript`, who may never have touched `dojo` could use it on the question as well. Unless you are going to say we should require tgh rights on *all* the initial tags to use it (which will basically nullify it)

Comment: ... then the presumption remains that someone who is one of the top guys in a tag has the sense/responsibility to use it properly within that tag.

Answer (score -11):

The whole point of the mighty hammer is to stem the tide of crap in high-volume tags. If you cannot wield it because your favourite tag is not high-volume, then that tag does not need this magical power in the first place.

Comment: Surely it can be used to stem the tide of all crap? Why restrict it to an elite set of tags and sod the rest? Our crap is no less crappy.

Comment: @ChrisLätta: The point is that the mighty hammer is an incredibly blunt and powerful instrument that, under normal circumstances, would never be used. Community voting is _always_ morally the best approach. We only have the superpowers in high-volume tags because the existing ethical approach is insufficient. That is not the case for your low-volume tags, where the "default case" of democracy should remain in place until the last possible moment. It has nothing to do with "eliteness" — what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: The problem is that in low volume tags you will likely never get the 5 votes needed to close a duplicate. I agree that democracy is the best approach but for democracy to work you need a critical mass of voters. The mighty hammer is actually more useful in a low volume tag because that is the only way duplicates will get closed. In high volume tags you can more easily rely on democracy because you have enough voters. However, there the might hammer is dealing with volume issues. The same solution solves both problems - not enough voters or too much crap.

Comment: @ChrisLätta: But in a low volume tag no one has answered enough to prove that they are worthy of such despotic powers. It's a very slippery slope to start doling out moderator powers to anyone who's posted ten answers just because the tag only _has_ ten answers.

Comment: No one is suggesting to just hand out powers to people on their first day. If you look at @DimitriM's answer he has sensible criteria to prevent abuse - the user must be in the top 20 for the tag and have the yearling badge, reviewer badge, silver or bronze tag badge, plus the tag itself having a critical mass of questions. I have answered over 250 questions in the `reporting-services` tag - in a higher volume tag that has more voting I would already have a gold tag badge and we wouldn't be having this conversation. As it is, I only have a bronze tag badge and duplicates are going unclosed.

Comment: "in a low volume tag no one has answered enough to prove … they are worthy of such despotic powers." Sure they have. In my own SO corner, I'm currently top in [tag:sparql], where I've answered 292 questions with a total score of 589. It's not a matter of not answering enough questions,  it's a matter of not having enough traffic to upvote those answers and get the rep for a gold badge.  I recognize lots of duplicates because I answered lots of them the first time. :)  That makes it easy to VTC as duplicate, but the same problem occurs: not enough traffic, not enough close votes.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: That is not enough to prove that you are worthy of such despotic powers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, not of *all* despotic powers, I suppose.  I just want to be able to clean up duplicates quickly, because in these low traffic tags, there aren't presently enough close votes to get the job done quickly.  Based on lots of other comments around here, it sounds like lots of people have similar opinions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I **do** think that you make a very good point about "The whole point of the mighty hammer is to stem the tide of crap in high-volume tags," in that low-traffic tags don't have as high a craptide as high traffic tags, but just like there is proportionately less crap, there are proportionately fewer close votes to clean it up, so it sticks around longer.  In high traffic tags, the crap moves quickly, but there's still too much.  In low traffic tags, there's too much, but it's stagnant.  If not a mighty hammer, we need some Augean shovels.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Don't get me wrong; I understand _why_ you want this and why it might seem unfair that you don't already have it.

Comment: I understand your point, but isn't this topic a request to enlarge the scope of the hammer to lower volume tags as well? I mean, there's a lot of garbage at these tags as well, but nobody ever looks at it and the people who look at it are unable to close it due to the 5 people thingy. It's like garbage under your bed, 99% of the people doesn't see it, but it's there and it smells.

Comment: @DimitriM: It's more like 99% of the people can neither see nor smell it. :)