# Notification that I have earned Curious badge, but not earned in reality

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

This happened only on StackOverflow site:

> [image]

The badge was not added to my badges. Why?

> [image]

Comment: Looks like *none* were awarded on Stack Overflow. It just sent out notifications...

Comment: I suspect that the process failed in the middle and only notifications went out. Please listen to the nice on-hold music while the developers figure out why.

Comment: Same here, no real badge.

Comment: I wonder if SO is just so big that it's going to take a little while before it shows up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wait, I get music when my question is put on hold?

Comment: I got my So Crates badge on C.SE http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/badges/107/socratic?userid=4 !

Comment: This notification, as of the time on this comment, displays in all of the several SE sites to which I subscribe. Looks like a bug of some sort.

Comment: @hichris123: please listen to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g4dkBF5anU while we figure out why you don't hear music when your question has been put on hold.

Comment: And all those who have earned the _Curious_ badge shall also be awarded bitcoins.

Comment: @MrBoJangles: you always see notifications on any SE site you are logged in. As far as we know it is only Stack Overflow where he badge process failed, however.

Comment: @devnull: Is that you, [Tim Draper](http://dealbook.nytimes.com/2014/07/02/venture-capitalist-tim-draper-wins-bitcoin-auction/)?

Comment: Yeah, I got two notifications this AM, on sites I hadn't visited in months.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm a [bot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_bot).

Comment: We don't need no [stinking badges!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges)

Comment: I am curious as to where my curious badge has gone

Comment: The badges are currently being sent out, if you refresh http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious you'll see the number rise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, the thing is for example, on gaming.se, the little symbol is that of a pixelated coin, bicycles.se it's the little gear symbol, etc. This ambiguity leads to my confusion. I seem to have earned the badge on all of the sites and on none of them.

Comment: Although, I see that's just normal. The symbol that matters is the one to the left of that! The one I was referring to is presumably dictated by the stylesheet. My bad, as the kids no longer say.

Comment: What's fun about this badge is that you have to earn five silvers and do something else to earn this bronze. Which is cool, just an observation.

Comment: @Cole9350 Curiouser and curiouser!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This badge was newly introduced today, and so it was retroactively awarded to over 130000 users. That kind of volume unfortunately isn't what the awarding process is optimized for. You already (sort of) had the badge when the notification was sent, but it only registered when all the new badges were handled. We're looking at ways to improve this, but in the normal case this delay won't happen.