# What's the meaning of "well-received question" and of "maintaining" a question?

Tags: support, badges

I just got this badge, and can't get the point, what I got it for.

> Curious
> Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record.

I would think maintain could mean editing, but why then not just call it so even if it just means edited?

Anyway I can't figure out the meaning of "well-received".

Comment: Search around on Meta or [meta.se].

Comment: Please see this MSE question: [Asking days badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/229438)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Congratulations! You received a badge for asking questions on 5 separate days where none of those questions had a negative score, or were deleted or closed!

Quoting from the [central badges FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> #### Curious
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record
>
>   - Any open question that is not deleted and has a of score >= 1 is considered *well-received*
>   - Only days where *all* questions asked have remained open and not deleted, with a score of zero or higher, count ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262301/badges-for-habitually-asking-well-received-questions))
>   - A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted) / total questions >= 0.5`. Questions that have been downvoted *and* closed *and* deleted count three times in this calculation!
>   - If a question was closed or deleted more than 60 days after it was posted, the post is counted as if it was not closed or deleted ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362920)).

*To maintain* here means *to keep in existence or continuance; preserve; retain*. In other words, looking at *all* your questions ever asked they continued to be in good standing. Here it means that your *total* number of questions is not overly burdened by a number of questions that were deleted, or downvoted or closed.

*Well-received* means that on those 5 days, your questions were not downvoted, deleted or closed; instead they ended up with a score of 1 or higher.

We cannot see if any questions you asked were deleted; if we assume there are 0 such posts, then you have 59 total questions, 5 are closed and 4 have a negative score, making your overall ratio (59 - 5 - 4) / 59 equals 0.847, which is greater than 0.5.

You have asked questions on 26 separate days, where all questions asked that day were not deleted or closed or had a negative score, where at least one question has a score >= 1 as well. That's more than the 5 required for Curious.

If you ask another 4 well-received questions on 4 separate days, you'll also gain the [Inquisitive badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4128/inquisitive)!

Again, this is all based on the assumption that there are not (many) deleted questions as well; those can affect the number of qualifying days *and* your positive question record. It may be that you'd have to ask more well-received questions to qualify for the next badge.

If you wanted to check your progress, you could use [this SQL query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges). Note that deleted posts are not part of the data set, so the query can't accurately calculate the positive question record.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I am still confused on "maintain". Is the positive question record calculated only at the point of checking for badge award, or for every past question?

Example: first 2 questions were well-received, 3rd one was not and caused a negative question record at that point. Qs 4-6 were well-received. All questions posted on different days. After Q6 got it's first upvote, the question record becomes positive. Does the curious badge got awarded then, or does the negative value during Q3 means that the person failed to "maintain" a string of positive question record?

Comment: @Ricky: the badge is awarded in batches, and the criteria are checked then. It's a SQL query; *give me all qualifying questions grouped by user, and make sure that each of those users has a positive record and no such badge*. All users in that query are then awarded the badge.

Comment: @Ricky: the positive record is calculated across all questions; so if by Q6 the record is positive again the badge could be awarded.

Comment: If someone deletes their own question, is that counted the same as if someone else deletes it?

Comment: @Suragch: the deletion counts regardless of whom deleted it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly at all. I have 6 questions, 1 of which has -ive score so it should qualify and it still says I need a positive question record. It has been like this for weeks. How often does the script run?

Comment: @RobbieDee: where do you have 6 questions? I see 35 on Stack Overflow (including deleted questions).

Comment: Sorry, on the programmers site.

Comment: @RobbieDee: I can't see how many *deleted* questions you have there. Those do count against you if you have any.

Comment: Is there a way I can see these?

Comment: @RobbieDee: you can look for *deleted recent questions* on your [Questions tab](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/73508/robbie-dee?tab=questions) (there will be a *deleted recent questions* link there); only questions posted in the last 6 months are going to be visible there. Any posts older than than will require a Programmers moderator to list for you. I'm pretty certain that that is what is holding back that badge for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, that is helpful. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @RobbieDee: in your case, all it takes is one downvoted, closed *and* deleted question for your ratio to drop below 0.5. That one question would count against you 3 times; you'd have 7 questions, and a 'penalty' of -4, putting you at 3/7 == 0.43. If that's the case, then just *one* additional question would boost you back to 0.5. It doesn't even need to be upvoted, it just needs to boost your total question count.

Comment: how do i see how many closed/deleted questions I have?

Comment: @ACE: you can only see deleted recent posts; your answers and questions tabs in your profile each contain a link to those; only posts created in the past 60 days, but since deleted, are listed there. You'll need to ask a moderator if you want to know how many questions older than 60 days you have that are deleted. You have 4 deleted questions, only one is recent.

Comment: Do they need to be in a row? Can the record reset the count?

Comment: No, they don't have to be in a row.

Comment: What does downvoted mean? If a question has 8 upvotes and 1 downvote is it considered downvoted? Or only if its total score is below 0?

Comment: @user889742 sorry, that is indeed a little ambiguous. The badge counts questions with a *negative total score*, so more downvotes than upvotes.

Comment: After all these years, I *just* realized that "record" is not a synonym of "highscore" in that sentence.

Comment: Could you please the actual equation at the bottom for better visibility? (total questions - negative questions - closed - early deleted)/total questions >= 0.5

Comment: I'm assuming closed as duplicate is the same as closed for any other reason here?

Comment: @ruohola: yes, if a post is closed as a duplicate it counts as a closed post.