# Why is a question not considered well received unless it has a score > 0?

Tags: discussion, badges

For some of the rules and badges on the site, there is a concept of a "well received" question.  [This post explains what that means very concisely.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262814/whats-the-meaning-of-well-received-question-and-of-maintaining-a-question)  However, it isn't clear to me why all zero score questions should not be considered well received.  For example, why should a question be considered well received if it receives multiple answers and comments, and no downvotes, but also no upvotes?

Intuitively a question with no upvotes and several answers might be trivial or a duplicate, but [consider my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511396/is-there-a-way-to-define-something-like-a-c-struct-in-verilog).  I don't think it would count as either, but I presume that it hasn't gotten enough attention for upvotes because the topic is somewhat obscure.  It's possible that it isn't a good enough question to be considered well-received, but the answers and comments have not led me to that conclusion.  EDIT: someone upvoted it since I posted this.  At the time its score was 0/0.

I have looked all over meta but I have not found an explanation for the thinking behind this choice.  Was this done to circumvent a specific kind of abuse, or is there another reason?  To be clear, I am not suggestion a change in the policy.  I simply would like to understand better the thinking behind this choice.

Comment: I look at it like questions with a positive score are good, negative score questions are bad and zero score questions are meh (not horrible, but nothing special either).  The idea is to encourage people to write questions that are both well written and interesting (ie. not something I can google and the first 10 results all answer the question).  A zero score, to me, usually means the post hasn't quite met that level of good-ness.  It was received, just maybe not *well*-received.

Comment: too complicated and overthought. If it's answered multiple time and commented on, but nobody thinks it's worth upvoting anyway, how is that well-received?

Comment: In my experience: questions with 0 upvotes, 0 downvotes and multiple answers are very, very basic and/or duplicates. I do not receive these well.

Comment: Score != # of upvotes. Say a question has a score of 101/100. Would you say that's a well received question?

Comment: I guess there isn't a solid definition of "well received", although I don't think this question should receive downvotes

Comment: You aren't describing a "restriction."  AFAIK there's no system artifact that responds to questions having a score of zero.

Comment: The type of question the OP is describing isn't "well-received", it's simply "received".

Comment: @JeroenVannevel questions like this are not necessarily basic or duplicates.  For example, my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511396/is-there-a-way-to-define-something-like-a-c-struct-in-verilog

Comment: The true "value" of a question isn't known until it has been around for a year or more and googled by hundreds of programmers.  Some pretty trite questions that never attracted an upvote in the first few days after it was posted do tend to draw lots of googler votes in the long term.

Comment: @remyabel This is a good point, but couldn't the system also consider this?  Might it make sense to consider a question that has no downvotes different from a question with equal upvotes and downvotes?

Comment: The harsh number of downvotes on this question seems unfair. Yes, there is indeed too little voting on good questions. It seems unfair to have the system basically say "meh" about a question like the one you link to. However, there is plenty of 0-voted garbage that should absolutely not lead to badges! I don't think this problem will ever be fully solved; trying to encourage critical, knowledgeable people to upvote good stuff (while keeping other people from upvoting *everything*) seems the only way to go - and that is a hard problem in itself....

Comment: I would point out that [about half](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+score%3A0..0+locked%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+is%3Aquestion) of the questions on Stack Overflow are 0 score open questions. It really shouldn't be the case that these are all eligible for being "good" questions.  This includes such questions as "[Is there a recommendation for a hardware platform for developing/testing SideShow devices, or is the Emulator adequate?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35720/)" and "[Is the Sql Server 2008 control available for download?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32941/289086)"

Comment: Why would you consider a zero-score question as "well received" and something that should count as credit toward a badge? It hasn't been "well received", because it has zero votes. Comments don't count; if the commenters thought the question was worthy of an upvote, they would have done so. Even zero vote scores with answers (even an accepted or highly upvoted answer) aren't well received if none of those reading or answering it felt it was worth an upvote. Well-received is not defined as "Blase, but good enough not to close or delete"

Comment: **Thursday-Rule-of-Loquaciousness** : I will babble along the crowd if weekend is Nigh.

Answer (score 2):

From your link:

> Any open question that is not deleted and has a of score >= 1 is considered well-received

When I think of this, it seems fair enough.  You bring up the point about having a score of "0" - well, you could say that it has the *potential* to become "well-received, according to Stack culture"

But nowhere does it say that " score <= 1 is considered poorly-received"

Perhaps you're right, in some cases an outstanding but obscure question is not going to get 1 vote.

In *those* cases, a meaty bounty like 200 or 500 points will rectify the situation *swiftly* - I guarantee or your mony back

Now, let me get back to this cup....

EDIT: To say we need **ONE** vote is absolutely arbitary here. StackOverflow could have said well-received = 5 upvotes. And I think it's a fair argument, to prevent drive-by votes.