# How to 'maintain a positive question record'?

Tags: discussion, badges

The description of the **Curious** badge

> Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record

The *Next badge* bar shows *5/5* as in the picture in the bottom.

[image: Curious badge]

But it also shows this (emphasis mine)

> Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and **maintained a positive question record**

What does it mean, 'maintained a positive question record'? What does it mean, 'need positive question record'?

Comment: Or maybe this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262814/whats-the-meaning-of-well-received-question-and-of-maintaining-a-question