# Do questions asked on meta count towards "positive question record" on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

In this link the "positive question record" term in the "curious, inquisitive, socratic, etc." badges are carefully explained. However, it is not clear whether questions asked on meta apply also to that?

I only ask because I was confused why I didn't get a badge, but I think I understand now that it needed to wait until the end of the day so that it could see if I ask a bad question and cancel out that day?

Maybe a good idea to edit that post to make this info explicit? :shrug:

Link: [What's the meaning of "well-received question" and of "maintaining" a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262814/whats-the-meaning-of-well-received-question-and-of-maintaining-a-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The main site's badges and Meta's badges are not linked together.  If you qualify for the badge on Meta, this does not imply that you qualify for the badge on the main site.