# Curious badge progress not getting updated

Tags: support

I am just trying understand how the Curious badge works. I have asked a lot of question so far and seemed to get a not so bad response on them, but still my tracker shows 2/5.

Just trying to understand, and nothing else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "well-received question" and of "maintaining" a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262814/whats-the-meaning-of-well-received-question-and-of-maintaining-a-question).  But the gist of it that "well-received" means a score of 1 or more.  You have a decent question history but only two questions with a score at 1 or more.