# Jon Skeet asked only 50 questions, but it shows 51/100 on his progress to Socratic

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, activity-tab

[Jon Skeet's activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=topactivity)

[image]

Comment: You deserve a gold badge for those connected circles.

Comment: Can we stop looking into other people's wallets...? (I mean _profiles_ in this case but it doesn't matter) It starts becoming distasteful.

Comment: This is so because...Jon Skeet. (Incidentally - in my continuing quest to become stupid-rich without expending actual work I'm considering founding The Church Of @JonSkeet. Any takers? I don't have much money yet, but I figure I'm about half way there :-)

Comment: When you find a bug on Jon Skeet's profile, it's actually a feature

Comment: Jon Skeet indirectly asked this question, where is the 51st question (which itself is the 51st question). He probably just wanted to point out this bug so he also provided a test case while doing so.

Comment: Wait, Jon Skeet asks questions? I thought he already knew everything.

Comment: @Nyerguds Jon doesn't ask questions. It's questions that seek out to Jon.

Comment: @Skipper the "wallets" are public for a reason: they document the fundation of reputation, and they're exactly what makes SO work in the first place.

Comment: @Skipper It's _activity_, in fact, not _profile_. And entire industries make a huge fortune from people looking at other people's activities: Hollywood, CNN, NFL, YouTube, YouPorn, ... you name it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

So looking into this a bit further, simply saying "closed" or "deleted" is not entirely accurate. The system actually checks that they were closed within 60 days and deleted within 60 days.

Now, I was aware of those criteria, but I *thought* the 60 days part only applied to calculating the score that needs to be greater than 0.5 in order to be considered a "positive question record" overall, and that any closed or deleted question did not count as a well-received question. That's... not true.

In reality, the 60 days requirement also applies to the count. So, if the closure or deletion of a question did not occur within 60 days of the question being asked, then it is permanently exempt from those two checks and (as long as its score is greater than 0) will always count as a well-received question even if it is closed or deleted.

That is why Jon seemingly has a higher count than questions that exist. Many of his early questions were closed and deleted long after they were asked, when the site's scope began to narrow. Those closures *and* deletions are ignored.

Comment: Cool! That makes sense. Now, someone will need to update the FAQ over on Meta.SE :-)

Comment: So it’s 45 days for the publicly visible posts, plus 5 for the remaining deleted posts with positive score. That leaves one but I’m guessing one of the undeleted but closed posts counts (closed outside the 60 day window).

Comment: @MartijnPieters The score has no 60 day requirement. That one is just whatever the current score is. Some of his *undeleted* questions were also closed well after 60 days, and still count as well.

Comment: Yup, comment already updated :-)

Comment: *shrugs* When I run the query locally he has 51 separate days that qualify (54 separate days, 2 disqualified due to deletions, 1 disqualified due to closure). I'm not going to count manually. ;P

Comment: I updated my SEDE query, his undeleted posts make up 48 days now :-) I can’t be bothered to count the delete posts right now, way too late at night.

Comment: If a question has gone down to zero *after 60 days*, it's not exempt from the calculation, unlike closure and deletion, right?

Comment: @iBug: Right, score is not protected by the 60-day rule.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Nice to know I'm not completely crazy!

Comment: @Ed I mean, that other answer you referenced is still completely wrong, just slightly less wrong. ;)

Comment: @animuson That's fair. :) I meant that I had in my head that questions deleted after some period of time could still be "well-received," and that part wasn't crazy.

Answer (score 25):

Not a bug; it turns out posts closed and/or deleted more than 60 days after posting count as well-received. So several deleted and closed questions still count.

Below is my original (wrong) post, but note that I updated my SEDE query to account for the 60-day exemption for closures; not counting deleted posts there are now 48 days counted, the deleted posts disqualify one of the 48 days but add another 4 qualifying days, making a total of 51 days.

---

It appears that *deleted posts* are being counted in the progress bar, while clearly they should not.

Just looking at the publicly available posts, Jon Skeet has asked well-received questions on [45 separate days](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229495/progress-towards-curious-inquisitive-and-socratic-badges?UserId=22656); these are days on which Jon only posted questions where a) at least one has a score greater than 0, b) none have a negative score, c) none of these are now closed and d) **none were deleted**.

Jon also asked 7 additional questions that have since been deleted, which I as a moderator can see. Of these 7, 6 of these have been asked on days Jon had not asked other questions, but since one of these was asked on the same day as another non-deleted question was posted Jon really has only 44 qualifying days.

These deleted posts **do not count towards the badge**, but 44 + 7 is 51.

Comment: Is this already reported on MSE?

Comment: @gparyani: I don't know.

Comment: Why not file a report there?

Comment: @gparyani: because I haven't had time to yet?

Comment: @gparyani: besides, the developers can see bug reports here too.

Comment: I'm getting super confused. Do Qs deleted after 60 days **(A) really count**? Or **(B) not count, but erroneously shown in the progress**?

Comment: @iBug they really count.

Comment: What does your last paragraph mean? It says *do not count*...?

Comment: @iBug: that’s the part of my answer that’s wrong. I added the part about the line later, after Animuson showed that certain closures and deletions are exempt.