# How do I view deleted or closed questions of my own?

Tags: support, badges, deleted-questions

Back to this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262814/whats-the-meaning-of-well-received-question-and-of-maintaining-a-question) I am trying to check why I did not receive the "Curious" badge even I had 5 well-received questions, After some research, I found The formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted) / total questions >= 0.5` but I kind of forgot if there are any questions I have deleted in the past, so is there any way to check how many questions I deleted before getting 10k reputation?

Comment: You need a mod who is wiling to post links to those posts

Comment: You have 6 deleted questions, all of which have scores less than or equal to 0: [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/58103850) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/48138016) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/48041905) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/47911403) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/43618849) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/40613943). None were deleted recently enough to be seen in your [recently deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/4171008).