# Has Stack Overflow performed any "social experiments"?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

In light of the recent revelation that [Facebook has conducted social experiments on its users](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2014/06/facebook_unethical_experiment_it_made_news_feeds_happier_or_sadder_to_manipulate.html), I wonder (actually not only for that reason, but from seeing the up/down voting that happens) if Stack Overflow has ever,

1. Generated posts, either questions or answers,
2. Generated up/down votes for said posts,
3. Populated data whether posts that may be of acceptable quality get undue bad attention and subsequently put on hold, deleted, etc.

I'm not trying to suggest that the voting that takes place is undue, rather that voting in general plays a role in user activity.

Comment: We're all Shog's lab rats. The Stack Exchange team analyzes question and answer data all the time. Is this supposed to secretly be a complaint that "good" questions are getting downvoted, closed, and deleted "unfairly"? Also, the cake is a lie.

Comment: @Cupcake: I'm certain they analyze data all the time, but are they "BIG-brothering" us??

Comment: Sure they are. The Stack Exchange sites are all a lie. They're just a cover for the CIA and the Illuminati to conduct tests on how long it will take for a group of nerds to start fighting each other to the death over little geeky trivia. They know everything about you. Your email address. Your IP address. How much time you spend on Stack Exchange. Etc.

Comment: I cannot help but think the real, for some definition of "real", answer is "Stack Overflow is *The* Social Experiment". On further thought, Meta.SO might be closer to The answer…

Comment: @Cupcake: well at least I'm auto-deleted from the FAA watch list.

Comment: Stack Exchange is actually a front for the Amish movement.  They're using this to find the best programmers in America.  Then, when they're ready, they'll strike at us eliminating the internet from American life and forcing the survivors of the collapse into agrarian living conditions to survive.

Comment: should be migrated to [skeptics.se]...

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're altering my feed so that I only see bad questions

Comment: Do anti-social experiments count?

Comment: It sounds like you think we might be trying to perform psychological experiments on you.  How does that make you feel?

Comment: Judging by the comments this post is generating, I think it might be a good idea to tag this with [`[fun]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fun)...

Comment: @OGHaza There are only bad questions.

Comment: I believe I can put forward definite proof of such experiments. Look who asked this question: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5136/toddler-bike-seat-vs-bike-trailer

Comment: @ntoskrnl Might as well link to that user's page: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/1684/eggs-mclaren

Comment: @AustinMullins Yes, but if it's a "puppet test account", then why is it used to post seemingly legitimate questions if not for social experiments? ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell, considering since I started using overflow I've become less social, at least in the traditional sense, yes.

Comment: @Jaydles, all tingly inside.

Comment: You shouldn't have asked that question!  Now you'll be hearing footsteps behind you for the rest of your life.

Comment: Is this a social experiment?

Comment: @Sklivvz wrong, this is not about SE, but SO in general. It's also just a general inquiry, not skepticism regarding a claim.

Comment: Do `unicoins` sound familiar?

Comment: @MarcGravell: You made me laugh pretty hard, that was a great comment.

Comment: Would these test be considered SOcial experiments?

Comment: Free usage of the downvote button or close voting could maybe be seen as some kind of Milgram experiment. After all the idea is to train people to ask the right way. :)

Comment: @Cupcake: the CIA, MI6, Mossad, whatever-the-KGB-morphed-into, Illuminati, Elucidated Brethren Of The Ebon Night, etc, blah, and a host of other secretive organizations have no, repeat NO, interest in SE. None. Really. And count your lucky stars they don't, because if they DID they'd have to have a short and pointed conversation with you. So you're safe. Completely safe. Sleep well tonight, secure in the knowledge that psycho ninja warriors are just SO not going to swing through your open window and hack you to bits in your bed with a +3 Katana Of Slicing/Dicing/Chopping. Pleasant dreams.

Comment: @BobJarvis I'm not scared of any [psycho ninjas](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)! `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake: how are you on ghosts? :-)

Comment: The only place where they do tests is http://dev.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is NOT about Stack Overflow but about Stack Exchange and it should be posted on MSE instead.

Comment: @mehow, I don't agree; it IS about SO because that's the SPECIFIC site I'm curious about. If 10/10 OTHER SE sites performed Soc.Exp. twice-a-day, I could/would care less.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stack Exchange certainly does do some form of social experiments:

- The community moderators and staff sometimes post questions on beta sites to try and help increase activity.
- On [parenting.se], they held [a contest](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/665/contest-anything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-parenting-but-were-afraid-to) to try and increase question asking on the site.
- They occasionally change the close reasons to see how many people complain.

Okay, kidding about the last one, but the first two are basically experiments (in particular, they approach them scientifically, analyzing them to see how much of an impact they have on participation rates and such).  These experiments aren't on the sly, of course.

Comment: IMHO, it's *extremely* difficult to conduct social experiments when the users know it's happening. **But** you did actually produce a link that says "so we tried an experiment a few weeks ago." +1 for sure, and I'm probably going to have to give you the acceptance as well. Let me look over some others.

Comment: In this case it was only announced on meta, and given the experiment was largely on people who wouldn't read meta, it was still largely blind. Second, the experiment can still be valid if the users know the rules. 'Can we change behavior by changing the rewards' etc. Not identical to a blind study but still useful :)

Comment: I'd say it's fair if it was only Meta notified; in fact, how many overflow users are totally aware anyway? I'd have to say I'd agree that experiments *can* be conducted and thus valid where the users know but the "observer effect" is real and must be considered with the results.

Answer (score 82):

No, as far as I know, we've never manipulated posts/users/votes/comments/etc. in order to perform an experiment on unwitting users or for any other reasons except bugfixing/backfills.

That said, there's a bunch of scientific papers on us and we often collaborate with universities if they need to study us. [This is all done in the open](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%22stack+overflow%22&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=2009&as_yhi=). These are of course studies *on us*, not *by us*, and are typically made using publically available data.

Also, we regularly do A/B testing with our own platform, mostly to optimize UX and copy.

Comment: Oh goodie, scholarly documents to read. BTW, as far as your migration request, I'm not a skeptic, per say, I'm only curious. Mainly for the benefits that you've provided here.

Comment: Also, unless some "Edward Snowden" comes forward with incriminating documents, I'll have to take your word for it. Although, you're "in the bubble" as they say!!

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils and we totally don't have a database called PRIZM, honest

Comment: I'm the Stack Exchange NSA (no such ape) and I support this message.

Comment: Does the refusal include the "fake edits" used to "see if you're paying attention"?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis review audits are a quality assurance mechanism, not a social experiment.

Comment: Here is another list on Stack itself about academic papers that use Stack Exchange data: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data

Comment: @Laura: Kinda like how phone calls are monitored for quality assurance purposes, right?

Comment: "*for any other reasons except bugfixing*" - ah, there we have it! I know that issue #1 in your secret bug tracker is [world domination](http://xkcd.com/792/)!

Comment: I remeber that you guys changed the interesting or hot questions formula for some users and they did not know about it. Someone once complained on meta about a weird new behaviour... Does that count?

Comment: Is the data gathered by advertisers public too?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237062/does-stack-exchange-have-an-official-policy-on-honoring-do-not-track-browser-s

Comment: @devnull some of it, like quantcast, is. Traffic data in general isn't -- moderators see some but they can't disclose it.

Answer (score 55):

I think you've uncovered a conspiracy. Here's the theory: since 2008, Joel and Jeff have secretly been feeding nothing but good, **positive** questions into Stack Overflow users' question feeds. This went on for a couple of years, and everyone was **happy**.

Then, the Stack Exchange team did a switcheroo, and started feeding crappy, **negative** questions into users' feeds, so that was all they ever saw. Amazingly, users started becoming negative and **unhappy** too!

There must be some strong correlation between question quality and user happiness on Stack Overflow. The Stack Exchange team has been manipulating people's emotions *for years* without their consent!

### Use Your Mind, Not Your Eyes,

### See the Truth, Behind the Lies!

[image: Illuminati]

<sub>[All seeing eye](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminatus!#mediaviewer/Datei:All_seeing_eye.jpg).</sub>

Comment: I think it's more of a conspiracy than you think; it's not Joel and Jeff but **the majority of the userbase of the StackExchange network** that have switched from posting good, positive questions to posting negative questions. I propose we counteract this to tip the balance in our favour by posting **positive** questions ourselves!

Comment: I see, so you postulate that `status-declined` is the most successful study on human anger ever conducted? You might just be on to something there ...

Comment: I'm not sure whether Stack Overflow by itself performs any social experiments, but it seems to give a free hand to its advertisers to do so.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237062/does-stack-exchange-have-an-official-policy-on-honoring-do-not-track-browser-s

Answer (score 19):

I can think of one experiment: [How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo)

According to [this answer in "The Many Memes of Meta"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19500), it was an experiment by [Joel Spolsky, co-founder of Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky).  That seems to fit #1, "Generated posts".

Answer (score 16):

stackoverflow.com *is* a social experiment. Or, to be more precise, an 'anti-social' experiment. The whole idea is to try to suppress natural social tendencies that ruin forum sites. Since no one can tell if would work, it has to be classified as an experiment.

Comment: Must stay robot, must stay robot. Supress love, hate, anger. 0010110

Comment: @Trilarion There's a Tamil movie that relates to that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthiran

Answer (score 7):

Usually we have more than enough historical data to answer questions like [To what extent do badges influence behavior?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209781/to-what-extent-do-badges-influence-behavior) and [Is the bounty system effective?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238736/does-the-bounty-system-work) So there's usually no need to run experiments such as the ones you mentioned. Often the public data available to anybody (either via the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) or the [data dump](http://blog.stackexchange.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)) is sufficient. Occasionally, we use an internal version of that data that includes deleted content. This is necessary in order to remove survivor bias and related effects.

> 1. Generated posts, either questions or answers,

If you include [manually authoring](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/665/contest-anything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-parenting-but-were-afraid-to) questions, then yes. The background here might be interesting for you. We've been batting around ideas of how to increase the participation<sup>1</sup> on smaller sites (such as Parenting) and an obvious way to do that is to [encourage more people to ask more questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262301/badges-for-habitually-asking-well-received-questions). But what happens if our top users are spread too thin?<sup>2</sup> If the number of questions were increased by 50%, would the activity per question decrease? If so, by how much? There's no clean way to test that with historical data since increases in participation usually go hand in hand with increases in user population.

Several members of the Community Manager team spent a good deal of time collectively and individually planning how to test the hypothesis that increasing questions will not decrease the quantity or perceived quality of answers. We considered several methods, including creating anonymous accounts. In the end, we decided to simply start asking questions that we would like to have answered on the Parenting site.

Of note: we did not announce the experiment on meta. The primary reason was we did not want to bias users one way or another. On the other hand, there was no reason for us to do so. Many of us routinely ask and answer questions on Stack Exchange sites because it's good to [eat your own dog food](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000012.html). So while we hoped to learn something about how people on our sites operate, we also hoped to learn something about parenting. (And I, for one, [certainly did](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/4521/jon-ericson?tab=questions).)

A few years ago, we tried a [similar experiment with hot topics](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/can-stack-exchange-capitalize-on-hot-trends/). One of the conclusions:

> **Creating high-quality content ... is a challenge.**

It's doubly hard when you want to conduct an experiment that doesn't harm the community you are asking on. And yet, that's what we've aimed to do. Whatever we're trying to learn, it isn't worth the cost of losing your trust. which brings me to:

> 2. Generated up/down votes for said posts,

Occasionally we get emails from researchers asking us to do just this. We've politely declined because:

- The results are a foregone conclusion. There's even a [Wikipedia page describing them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwagon_effect).
- It would betray the trust of our users.

Quite simply, we won't mess with this sort of experiment.

> 3. Populated data whether posts that may be of acceptable quality get undue bad attention and subsequently put on hold, deleted, etc.

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean. We do think that our current algorithm for showing questions on the Stack Overflow home page [highlights bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so). (We are tackling that problem with a [variety of new and tweaked features](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project). We are also looking into [controlling the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta). Doing these things in a sensible way requires collecting a lot of data.

We also do [A/B tests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266353/1438) and test advertising campaigns. As far as I know, we don't purposely test *worse* experiences for our users. Instead, we either test potential improvements ("what happens if we make that button a little bigger?" sort of thing) or similar alternatives ("does the blue background get more clickthroughs than the orange?").

As a rule, **our interests are aligned with the success of our communities.** As a company we try very hard to make our decisions in public. That means we share what we are up to on meta—usually before we do it.

---

<sub>1. Since you asked here and not Meta Stack Exchange, I should emphasize that Stack Overflow has _never_ had a problem with low levels of participation. Most of it's life has been a struggle to [manage large volumes of content](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/).</sub>


<sub>2. Again, this may very well be an issue on Stack Overflow and a [handful of other sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you haven't visited the review queue very often.

Every single one of those things has happened.  They do so to make sure that the reviewers are actually paying attention.

Comment: No, especially if you don't consider every day often ;). This is a good shot though, but I'm going to say this is more of a pop-quiz. I haven't experienced anything where you could see a large number of votes trying to sway you one way or the other. For example, if a great answer was given but heavily down-voted along with comments from Jon Skeet kindly explaining why the poster was wrong type of thing. This would not be exposed at the time of your vote. The data would be compared to other attributes - rep, num_reviews, member_since, etc. And use that data to come to some conclusion.

Comment: I'd say anything Jon Skeet doesn't agree with can't possibly be called a "great answer"... but I see your point.

Comment: That *is* the point.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange has done one social experiment in which they allowed us to [chat with an expert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert).

The conversations had a permalink and users could publish them if they found them entertaining.

Comment: That's a good one, but it looks like it was only intended as a joke. Is there anything pointing to a hypothesis or conclusion?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils look at the date of the linked post. ;)