# Award tag badges multiple times?

Tags: feature-request, badges, tag-badges, badge-request

One of my favorite badges on this site are the tag badges - getting a gold tag badge is a pretty meaningful accomplishment! 200+ answers with a score of 1000+ indicates a lot of contributions that are considered very valuable to the community. However, it establishes something of a ceiling effect. What about people who do even better than that?

In C++ for instance, take somebody like a [Mike Seymour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour) who has 4,000+ posts with a score of 17,000+. Doesn't that deserve a few extra gold C++ badges? I'd like to think so. Plus now that I hit 1,000 recently, I'd like to have something to shoot for as well - since we all know that trying to earn fake badges is the best motivation!

I'd like to propose continuing the 2.5x jump from silver to gold ad infinitum. Or to copy [Yakk's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262341/2069064) proposal on a related question - make each difference 2x the previous one. Thus the gold tag badges would be awarded at:

- 1000 score, 200 answers
- 3000 score, 600 answers
- 7000 score, 1400 answers
- 15k score, 3k answers
- etc.

I do not believe that these additional badges would dilute the significance of a gold badge - as they are exceedingly hard to get. Across all tags, assuming I wrote my query correctly - I count 4,153 gold tag badges. This proposal would award an additional 828 "2x" badges, 200 "3x" badges, 36 "4x" badges, 8 "5x" badges, and 1 "Jon Skeet 6x" badge.

Comment: All of a sudden I'm not so proud of my 15k : 1.8k ratio in [css] anymore.

Comment: @Bolt, since you've been moderating the site at the same time you were answering, you should apply a `2.5` ratio to any activity that led to reputation income while actively moderating. *(Yes, I received my tax form today.)*

Comment: With this you give John Skeet another opportunity to break the layout/css from SO :)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. I'm getting fairly close to my first gold badge, and for me it will be the most meaningful badge I earned so far. It would be nice to have more to shoot for after that. Aside from gold badges in other tags, or course. There are other badges that can be earned multiple times, so it still fits into the existing badge scheme.

Comment: Excellent idea, would be sad if it would be ignored.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Guess not enough love for the multi-badge.

Comment: @Barry I assume mostly reluctance in adding new features.

Comment: cf. [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309071/allow-multiple-gold-badges-for-the-same-tag). Same community, same year, practically same proposal, radically different reception. Go figure....