# Allow multiple gold badges for the same tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, badges, tag-badges

Why not reward ⁄ incentivise high quality answer providers on a tag, with multiple gold tag badges in that tag, if they've earned it?

Simply go in multiples of the requirements, so a score of 1000 over 200 answers gets you a gold tag badge; 2000 ⁄ 400 gets you two of them; etc.

I'm not anywhere near getting that for myself, if you were wondering, so have no self-interest here. Just have come across [such a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran?tab=tags) by chance, and can't think of a reason why wouldn't they have 9 gold Java badges that they seem to have earned.

Comment: if you downvote, I'd *really* appreciate it if you'd state your reasons for disliking this. Because I really can't imagine why would that not be good. So please tell me.

Comment: Why multiple gold? Why not a `platinum' or 'diamond' or *'demi-god'* badge. At some point...a single badge is enough

Comment: multiple gold, precisely to avoid the new badges. multiple, because gold is the highest.

Comment: Oh...and the user you linked has 1 gold badge in Java. He has other gold badges as well.

Comment: @Paulie_D but they've earned 9 of them, in Java.

Comment: Speaking for myself, I don't think it would make sense to give me 49 gold Java badges, 85 gold C# badges etc, 25 .NET badges. It becomes a bit pointless. If the requirements were exponential, that might make a bit more sense...

Comment: I think it's unreasonable to ask users to carry more than one dupehammer.  Those Mjölnirs are heavy!

Comment: there would be only one hammer of course. the powers that come with the golden badge are orthogonal to the concept of badges and why they are on SO in the first place.

Comment: @JonSkeet there are exponentially more users with less than 5 badges (under my proposal) than users like you, :) and for them having e.g. 3 or 5 badges would still be meaningful.

Comment: I'm just saying that any proposal which ends up giving me a huge number of extra gold badges should be viewed with a certain amount of suspicion :)

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, don't follow. suspicion of what? --- SO is gamified, through badges among other things. If you earned 1000 badges in Java, why should you be denied them? I see no logic in that. --- those who earn multiple bronze badges are rewarded with a silver badge; same with silver/gold. But with gold, it's the abrupt end of that road, which makes no sense (to me).

Comment: Suspicion if it being a bad idea, that's all. Just like any rep calculation change that would give me significantly more rep.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for clarifying, though I can't see any validity in that heuristic. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Award tag badges multiple times?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291520/award-tag-badges-multiple-times)

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur of course not. ***there is no answers there*** for starters, so how could it?????? then, it contains ***two*** separate, radically different proposals, both different from mine here.

Comment: @WillNess that comment was auto-generated by Stack Overflow when I marked your question a duplicate.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur I know. what I'm saying, I disagree with your (and five other people's) judgment on this.

Answer (score -1):

See the [Java gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/java) description:

> Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. These users **can single-handedly mark java questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed**.

It's reasonable to assume that people with > 1000 score and 200 answers are experienced with Java questions and probably know how to handle them (close, improve and help when needed), I don't see added value in multiple earning of this tag.

This is only my opinion and I hope it explains my disagreement on this feature request, hence my downvote.

Comment: the added value would be "reward ⁄ incentivise high quality answer providers on a tag" as stated in the question.

Comment: "I don't see added value in multiple earning of this tag" *for yourself* you mean?

Comment: @WillNess correct.

Comment: badges are just flair. additional powers is not why they exist on SO. if you contributed more, why shouldn't you get more, in fair proportion to your contribution?

Comment: Because it's not about *us*...it's about the answers. SO doesn't owe us anything.

Comment: @Paulie_D so you disapprove of even the existence of badges on SO, in the first place?

Comment: No...they are a *general* indication of the level of competence and priviege but that's enough.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'm going to downvote your answer because it doesn't address the question as asked. "reasonable to assume" is total strawman, has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D notice I said "existence of *badges* on SO" not "tag badges".  because your comment ("SO doesn't owe us anything") can only be interpreted as opposition to the very existence of the badges system of incentivising/gamification, on SO. which is what my question is about. --- and, following your train of thought, why should 1001 tag-rep user be indicated as equal to 9999 tag-rep user? that would be a faulty indicator.