# I'm wondering why I'm not getting the Inquisitive badge on SO

Tags: support, questions, badges, badge-progress

[This is my non-deleted question history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956566/yvette?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=1). It has 32 positive questions asked on separate days. On one of those days I also asked a zero voted question. There are some negatively voted questions and maybe a dozen zero. I know there are some deleted questions.

The calculations for these types of badges is found here [What's the meaning of "well-received question" and of "maintaining" a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262814/whats-the-meaning-of-well-received-question-and-of-maintaining-a-question)

I'm wondering what is stopping me from getting the badge (it's been the recommended badge for ages). I can't see if it's the deleted questions or what is holding it up. I know there can be a lag with badges updating, but I'm wondering if there's another cause.

[image]

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262301/badges-for-habitually-asking-well-received-questions

Comment: Same for me. Mine hangs at 22/30. But I never wondered really, I'm asking rarely.

Comment: @DonkeyKong it's only just updated to 28. It's slow on that. I've used that trick for tag badges. But this one is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Jon's SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202534/asking-over-time-badges#resultSets) you have 29 eligible answers. My best guess is you missed a few where you deleted a question on the same day as a well-received question.

Comment: @Yvette You have a deleted, negatively-scored question on Aug 4 '15 which disqualified a well-received question on the same day.

Comment: @animuson thanks, I can't see most of my deleted questions. I prob should undelete the ones that have zero score, but can't see them to do it. What do you think?