# Privileges for tag-specific badges

Tags: support, badges, privileges, tag-badges

I know that holders of **gold** tag-specific badges have [certain closing privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212).

Are there any other *gold badge superpowers* or anything at all for bronze or silver badge holders?

Please note that I'm not suggesting that there *should* be any.  I'm merely inquiring about the status quo.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: To add to l4mpi's short answer, check out the suggestion over on MSE about what they _could_ add, but haven't yet: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240700/empowering-tag-badge-holders-part-ii-lets-look-at-silver

Answer (score 18):

In the status quo, there are no special privileges earned by holders of bronze or silver tag badges.
You just get the bragging rights, and a higher colored circle count on your user card/flair.

The ability of gold tag badge holders to cast a binding vote when marking a question as a duplicate is [a relatively new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders), and similar privileges have [been considered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240700/empowering-tag-badge-holders-part-ii-lets-look-at-silver) in [various contexts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260166/close-vote-superpowers-for-other-badges-in-low-volume-tags?rq=1) but not yet added for lesser tag badge holders.

Answer (score 10):

Nothing on the site itself. However:

Cody Gray has phrased it as bragging rights, but perhaps it can somehow be **more** highlighted on your developer profile (something StackExchange employees would have to do something) or you can just share a link on your resume and say the Stack Overflow community trusts me this much because I have earned this badge. (Though doing this is likely only good for new/young/junior developers)

To me it clearly outshines LinkedIn endorsements. I mean any Tom, Dick, and Harry can endorse anyone on LinkedIn, but on Stack Overflow there are measures in place to avoid fake reputation.