# Bronze and/or silver tag badge holders should earn additional privileges, like weighted close votes

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, tag-badges

I recently earned the Java bronze tag badge. I was very happy. But then I thought, what privileges did I earn?

I know that you can immediately close a question as duplicate if you have a gold badge on one of the tags of the question. But what about bronze and silver? Are there privileges associated with them?

If there isn't, why do we have bronze and silver tag badges in the first place? Unlike normal badges, we can't show off the tag badges in flair thingy. So I think they must have a purpose.

I suggest that maybe someone with a bronze tag badge can cast 2 or 3 close as duplicate votes on a question. And someone with a silver badge can cast 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Privileges for tag-specific badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287374/privileges-for-tag-specific-badges) (retracted).

Comment: @WaiHaLee That's not a duplicate - this is a feature request, the other is a request for support.

Comment: @Zizouz212 - good point. I've retracted my vote.

Comment: I'm pretty sure tag badges are included in the flair counts. As far as "purpose", historically none of the badges had any purpose. They were just for fun. The ability to insta-close a question as a duplicate if you hold a gold tag badge is a relatively new feature. There doesn't need to be symmetry all the way down.

Comment: Yep. I think the best thing about tag badges is you get to take them and wave your hands in the air... *I've got it! I've got it!* :P

Comment: ..or..  "I have a Java bronze badge:((  I swear I got it my accident after answering a few language-agnostic questions.  It was not intentional m'lud".

Comment: You are not fooling anyone, @Martin. Clearly you're an expert in multithreaded Java programming! Just wait until Careers catches wind of this.

Comment: @CodyGray I read it as a limited number of votes to insta-close, not fewer (weighted) votes to close.

Comment: @Petah I don't know, it says "on *a* question." If it was insta-close, why would you cast multiple votes on a single question? I could be wrong, though. I won't be offended by further edits.

Comment: @CodyGray  Careers??  Nooooo!  My spam filter is already groaning from the strain:(

Answer (score 1):

What privileges you earned with your new tag badge? None.

We had badges long before we had the "dupe hammer". In fact, the "dupe hammer" (aka Mjölnir) was invented to [solve a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders) - a very large number of questions that might need closing.
Stack Overflow gave some extra closing power to a select group - gold tag badge holders, who are expected to know how to wield this power.

It has been suggested to also [give extra power to silver tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240700/empowering-tag-badge-holders-part-ii-lets-look-at-silver), but so far this hasn't been implemented.

I wouldn't expect to see extra powers for bronze tag badges any time soon.

Comment: I believe it makes perfect sense to leave the close vote privileges with gold tag badge achievers. Gold tag badge is a clear-cut evidence that the said person has certainly spent enough time on the website solving questions of that tag. Tag badges aren't just reflective of that fact that the person has plethora of knowledge on a specific tag technology but he also knows as to what all kinds of questions get usually asked or have been asked in the past. This helps him make close/duplicate vote decisions more quickly and thoroughly.