# Should gold tag badge holders have the right to reopen "some" closed questions single-handedly?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently, *gold* tag badge holders have the right to single-handedly hammer close vote questions as a duplicate.  By allowing this we are saying that we respect the opinion of our gold tag badge holders enough to respect their decision as to what is in fact a duplicate and what isn't.

Given that logic, shouldn't we be able to respect their opinion with regard to questions that have been close voted, by the community?

A gold tag badge holder should have enough experience within this badge to be able to decide what is a good question and what isn't.

Consider if the question has been edited and improved since it was closed or even if the author added clarity in comments.  A gold tag badge holder may be able to see this question should not be closed.  They may even be able to answer it now.  However, they would need to wait until enough people agree with them that it should be reopened.  In low volume tags this can take hours or days.

I propose questions closed for these reasons:

- Unclear
- Need focus
- Needs debugging details (the tag holder may know there are enough details)
- possibly opinion based (if the tag holder can come with facts only)

Comment: Hammering is a dual between opening *and closing* as duplicate. What is the rationale behind extending it only to *opening* for other reasons?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i have never seen a dual,  I have had a user once deny my duplicate which i then removed single handled.  Working as intended I would think.  Reopening would give me the change to answer a valid question that had been closed while i was offline.   WIthout having to wait for enough people to allow me to do so.

Comment: We've seen disagreements between gold-badge holders before. I don't think allowing a single one to reopen a question 3 users think should be closed is a good idea

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377950/increase-close-and-reopen-vote-weight-for-tag-badge-holders https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253324/give-high-rep-users-extra-weight-on-close-votes https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317490/bronze-and-or-silver-tag-badge-holders-should-earn-additional-privileges-like-w

Comment: As a gold-badge holder I would much prefer that the community rules on re-opening the question if my intention was to "answer a valid question that had been closed while i was offline".

Comment: I feel like this request is missing something to really say *why* its good and especially not bad. Especially for the various close variants of "people don't understand the question right now", it seems not particularly useful to me that only an expert can understand it – rather the opposite.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Maybe you can explain why you would think reopening a valid question would be bad?   One that i could answer and would help someone.  Why make me wait hours or days to find enough people to agree with me?

Comment: @DaImTo Because it's not just about reopening "valid" questions.

Comment: Honestly, I think that just the ability to close/open unilaterally on duplicates is enough. My *personal* experience is that not enough gold badgers use their votes to close low quality and unclear questions, let alone "hammer" obvious duplicates (and instead answer them). Giving the power to unilaterally open questions that have been closed doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: @DaImTo And from a personal standpoint, because [SO] is increasingly degrading in value for me because the useful information is being drowned in heaps of noise by people trying to help each and every snowflake in their own special way. "I've got a gold bade and just want to help" is not what I would call a guarantee for quality. That you only care about opening does not help to build trust.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi some of us just want to help.  Rep doesn't matter its not like you get paid for doing this.   I dont get rep when i have to have people contact me on twitter so I can help them because their question was closed.  I would rather be a unicorn  personally.

Comment: Then help them by getting them to improve their question so it's reopened by the community, @DaImTo . If it's a duplicate, close it as a duplicate of a *good* high quality Q&A, so that they have a wealth of knowledge they can instantly consume and implement. Giving them their answer on a silver platter is, in my opinion, actually the least amount of help as far too many take that solution, don't read it, don't take the time to understand it, and can't actually properly implement or debug it. If the question is low quality, that Q&A is unlikely to help anyone else in the future either.

Comment: As a related topic, if you think that gold badgers should be able to unilaterally reopen questions that are unclear, need focus, etc, why do you not also propose they should be able to unilaterally close them as such too?

Comment: BTW,  Mr Miyagi said "dual", not "duel". ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring well, duels tend to be dual, so the duality of meaning is appreciated :)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: (FYI, [your comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417958/should-gold-tag-badge-holders-have-right-to-reopen-some-closed-questions-singl#comment909036_417958) has been commented on [outside of Stack Overflow](https://twitter.com/LindaLawtonDK/status/1523969299307806722).)

Answer (score 8):

> Given that logic. Shouldn't we be able to respect their opinion with regard to questions that have been close voted, by the community?

No; just because we trust someone to know what isn't a duplicate doesn't *necessarily* imply we trust them to know anything else...

But we probably should trust them more than that. As you wrote,

> A gold tag badge holder should have enough experience within this badge to be able to decide what is a good question and what isn't.

YES. This is [an issue I touched on a few years back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368875/should-very-low-quality-flags-be-offloaded-entirely-to-tag-experts/374490#374490):

> with the exception of Mjölnir and the original long-forgotten closing system, nothing we've ever done has really worked for tags with only a single knowledgeable user monitoring them.

This is still an issue. Getting knowledgeable eyeballs on stuff in niche (a.k.a. "long tail") areas is tough; when someone demonstrates their knowledge by answering a bunch of questions, we should be better about listening to them.

...that goes for closing AND REOPENING.

Critically: closing and reopening aren't quite symmetrical; especially for duplicates, the operation of closing requires finding and providing a link, while reopening does not. Yet, we trust badge holders to perform this operation based purely on their demonstrated knowledge of the topic! Why not extend that trust a little further...

Comment: On an off-note, doesn't this discussion tie in closely to plans to give more weight to close voters' votes in some cases?

Comment: Yes ([relevant discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375797/should-trusted-close-reopen-voters-and-reviewers-have-their-votes-weighted-more)) - though I don't think the proposal there goes far enough (also I tend to think votes from *outside* review are a bit more important in this regard, which conflicts with the premise of that thread a bit - but several others have pointed that out; I largely agree with TylerH's answer there).