# Why don't the tag badges include questions?

Tags: discussion, badges, tag-badges

The badge description for the bronze tag badge is:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki **answers** to achieve this badge.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Is there any reason that this doesn't include questions? I suspect that it's because having a badge in a topic indicates a level of expertise, which simply asking questions doesn't prove.

---

### New Badges?

If that is the case, is it unreasonable to request equivalent question badges? We'd all love more, essentially meaningless Internet accolades!

The behaviour I hope it would encourage is the same as the other question badges. That is, **asking better questions**. The numbers might need to be shifted a bit. Asking 200 questions, good questions on a topic might be a bit overkill for a gold badge.

I think asking questions is important to showing that you are skilled in a topic. **Knowing that you don't know something**<sup>1</sup> and being willing to ask a question is a skill itself.

---

<sup>1. Bit of an oxymoron!</sup>

Comment: I'd imagine this would favour (and potentially increase the amount of) self answered questions

Comment: @Sayse Maybe it could - but if it is a good question and good answer, why does it matter.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Its a subltety that means instead of 100 positive interactions with people, 50 positive interactions with people who wish to acknowledge either your question or answer by giving you more reputation could award you the badge. This counts further towards the gold badge where you get given more powers.

Comment: @Sayse, but if the content is good, let it be rewarded. The balancing of numbers can be changed.

Comment: @JamesWebster - I guess its just what I perceive the badge to be awarding, rather than rewarding the actual score I see it as rewarding 100 interactions with people - with the score just being a way to quantify this

Comment: This would absolutely have to have a lower cutoff for score (not just upvotes, score). Only at +2 or +3 could we have a reasonable surety that the question demonstrates the asker knowing what she doesn't know. But then we quickly run into a problem of low-traffic tag Q-badges being all but impossible to earn because even good questions don't get voted on in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We already have numerous badges to reward asking questions, I don't think having a badge related to asking questions in a specific tag would add any value.

The idea of the tag badges is to show expertise in the area (as you said), which I'm not sure asking questions would qualify.

Also, when a user reaches a gold badge for a tag, they get [super powers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212) under the current format.

Would you want someone that contributed a prolific amount of questions under a tag to have such powers?

Comment: "The idea of the tag badges is to show expertise in the *popular tags*". Gold tag badges are already spit in the face for people who answer in niche tags without you linking "expertise" directly with them :-) Or "The idea of the tag badges is to reward the, sometimes-wanton, voting patterns in the popular tags". "How do I add one and one and store the result as a string?" +491.

Comment: @BillWoodger not sure if you've seen this, but I back the suggestion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260166/close-vote-superpowers-for-other-badges-in-low-volume-tags

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've upvoted. I have answered 213 of 716 questions in my most popular tag. That got me silver, recently, but gold is far distant. One other silver in the tag (that user is no longer very active). Closing anything usually takes days, if it happens at all, and rare for a duplicate (we don't have many, but those I flagged previously were aged away).