# Does the tag summary work properly? How does it work?

Tags: support, tags, tag-score

I have 24 questions tagged with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), but the tag tab page shows -1 point. 
Why? Is this due to a bug or a complex calculation algorithm?

For me this tag should be put higher in the tag ranking, don't you think do?

Comment: only answers are counted in the tag score - notice when you hover over the -1 it says "Gave 7 non-wiki answers with a total score of -1". So those questions you asked with total score of 19 don't count in tag scores. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296639/why-dont-the-tag-badges-include-questions

Comment: Thanks for links. It's clear now.