# Answering questions when no attempt has been made

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, vote-to-close

Note the *closest* Dup I can find is on StackExchange Meta:

[**Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212)

There are 2 aspects to this post:

1. **Question**: Is it good practice to provide solutions from scratch when OP has *displayed* no attempt at answering their question? In other words, no code provided, but a code-based solution is expected.

   - I fall into this trap often myself. I *know* someone will answer quicker than the question will get closed [see #2], so I might as well provide a solution, even if it's usefulness (given it's a poor question) to a wider audience is limited.
   - Concrete example: ["Looking for a solution which can do this operation for millions of rows and create files automatically for each cookieid."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338515/selecting-values-of-a-column-and-look-for-that-value-in-2-dataframes)
2. **Suggestion**: Currently, it takes 5 votes to close a question that is too broad or unclear. In popular tags, by the time this happens, there are often one or more answers. Would it be possible to implement something like:

   - 3 Bronze or higher badge holders in a relevant tag can close down the question.
   - 2 Silver or higher badge holders in a relevant tag can close down the question.

My rationale is as follows. There are countless excellent answers to poor questions. Occasionally, the answerer (or an altruistic contributor) edits the question so it is more meaningful to a wider audience. Implementing the above suggestion will make it more likely we have *good questions* associated with those excellent answers.

**Edit #1**: This post is ***not*** about giving Bronze/Silver holders extra privileges. Nor is it about specifically giving high-rep users extra privileges.

I would be equally happy with 2 Gold holders being able to close down a non-duplicate (but very poor) question. It seems inconsistent that 4 Gold holders cannot close a broad / unclear question, but 1 can close a duplicate.

**Edit #2**: From [2014 post on Gold badge dup hammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/383944):

> This is being deployed initially as an experiment, I think there's
>   enough sanity here to prevent most abuse cases, and we don't really
>   have a very large rate of incorrect duplicates. If this pans out well,
>   **we might consider giving gold tag badge holders more weight in other
>   areas, and possibly considering silver tag badge holders**.

*I'd say the Gold badge dup hammer was a resounding success.*

Comment: If you make a feature request about prevent no-research answer: How about doing some research yourself before. Bronze and silber super-power is a topic that is proposed almost every month: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317490/bronze-and-or-silver-tag-badge-holders-should-earn-additional-privileges-like-w), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260166/close-vote-superpowers-for-other-badges-in-low-volume-tags), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240700/empowering-tag-badge-holders-part-ii-lets-look-at-silver)

Comment: The reason why I didn't find your (apparent) dups, which are generally years old and sometimes have no accepted answer, is they all focus on giving bronze/silver holders extra privileges. My point is more general. Maybe you can have 2 gold badge holders close a question?

Comment: Not a dupe per se, it only addresses part 2 of the question. OP, why did you not make this two questions?

Comment: @JanDoggen, The reason I didn't ask the first question separately is the answer is obvious: "Take the right action: Close it and hope the system works with sufficient other users agreeing. If it doesn't, the worst that can happen is a few users post solutions before (if/when) the question gets closed." The reason it does *not* work is highlighted in the second part: not *all* of us [questioners + responders] see SO as a resource rather than a solution-providing service. Which is where gold holders can step in.

Comment: I like the suggestion but I don't understand how it's supposed to "make it more likely we have good questions associated with those excellent answers". I think it will just help closing bad question(which is a good thing).

Comment: "This post is not about giving Bronze/Silver holders extra privileges." Then what is it?

Comment: @jhpratt: "I would be equally happy with 2 Gold holders being able to close down a non-duplicate (but very poor) question." Please also see Edit #2.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338755/whats-better-a-question-with-no-attempt-or-with-an-unfixable-irrelevant-attemp. Now I think that you should split your question in 2. And provided that there's an answer to one part, your question is half a duplicate, or 2 half-duplicates. (not to mention that you've made yourself a friend below :))

Comment: see also [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/165773) at MSE

Comment: Something changed for the worse in the last four years; SE no longer cares about helping its most invested users tend to the site. As all the links in the comments demonstrate, this is [more wasted breath](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project#comment967316_285889), unfortunately. Best get used to the inadequate tools we have, and [vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364498/603977) for some more bodies to line the flag-handling queue.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, Post that as an answer and I'll accept :). 4 years, in my view, is ample time to see if an experiment worked. Words should be backed up with action.

Comment: Eh, expanding that comment would just produce [this again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth/351792#351792).

Comment: Another one over on MSE: [Let's give very trusted users a closehammer to go with their dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256657)

Comment: This is one of the areas that is bad on these stack exchange sites. I find 10 close votes on my system works better, and never give weight to it. A while back, someone with high rep edited my correct answer to a post which caused my rank to drop. I ended up deleting the answer and ever since then, I'm not going to post answers.

Comment: The solution doesn't seem to fit the problem. The proposed new power helps to close bad questions *quickly,* but that is not specific to no-effort questions. Wouldn't it be better to add a new closure reason ("question shows no effort to solve the problem, and instead simply asks for code")?

Comment: [The question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49338515/1709587) doesn't look awful to my (inexpert) eye; I see a reasonable (but maybe duplicate) question hidden in there (roughly, "how do I join two Pandas dataframes by a common ID column?") masked beneath an unclear title and some irrelevant details about the data coming from a CSV. But whatever its merits, I think you're wrong to complain about the lack of an attempt exhibited in the question. How would that help you answer or make the question more useful to future viewers? I put it to you that it would do neither, at all.

Comment: @MarkAmery, the idea is that the question would be rewritten with example code including (usually) a common pitfall. Then the answer will explain what went wrong, correct the code, provide an explanation, and possibly provide a better solution. SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: I would really like to see high-rep users get more weight for their close votes. I also [proposed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) awhile back reducing the number of close votes required to close questions (so only 3 or 4 "normal" close voters).

Comment: `I fall into this trap often myself. I know someone will answer quicker than the question will get closed [see #2], so I might as well provide a solution` sounds like terrible reasoning to answer crappy questions, if you ask me

Comment: @COLDSPEED. That's subjective. Many disagree with you, whether they admit it or not. They believe answers are for providing solutions to specific users (cf. all the great answers I see each day to poor questions). So, unfortunately, your remark comes across rather flippant.

Comment: @jpp *"SO isn't a code-writing service"* - I find this (frequently repeated) refrain consistently unhelpful, both because I'm unclear on what *precisely* it's supposed to mean, and because it seems to only be used (as it is here) to demand that askers convert their "How do I do X?" questions into "Why doesn't my attempt at X work?" questions. Okay, so we're not a *"code-writing service"*; are we then a *"debugging service"*? If not, why does artificially converting a how-to question into a debug-this question by sprinkling it with broken code make it *better*?

Comment: @MarkAmery Your thought was posed formally as a MSE question some time ago: [How does "proof of effort" make a question better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179035) (And I think there's a similar one on MSO, but can't find it at the moment.) (Actually, that probably was an MSO question when it was posted -- before the Meta split.)

Comment: Oh, this one's good too, from way back: [Are code troubleshooting questions really what we want to encourage?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107116)